# Declare global variables in codebehind file

Tags: c#, asp.net

In the code below, how do I declare totalSquareFeet and other variables global so that when I parse data from asp.net textboxes it becomes accessible to other methods specifically performAnalysisButton button method?

Note that the code below is not complete. I have deleted most of the code to keep my question as simple as possible. To give you a background following are the purposes of 2 buttons:

- okButton_Click: Take the data from textboxes (created in asp.net webform) and perform some calculations and display results in labels.
- performAnalysisButton_Click: Take the data from aforementioned textboxes and perform some calculations and display results in another textbox.

In short, all the local variables that I have declared under the okButton_Click method, I would like to use them under performAnalysisButton_Click method. I was wondering if there is a way I can avoid parsing the textbox data again?

```
    public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Create objects for fiscal year end dates (e.g. 12/31/17)
            FiscalYearEnds fiscalYearEnds = new FiscalYearEnds();
            firstFiscalYearEndLabel.Text = String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", fiscalYearEnds.firstFiscalYearEndDate());
            secondFiscalYearEndLabel.Text = String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", fiscalYearEnds.secondFiscalYearEndDate());            
        }

        protected void okButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Parse values
            int totalSquareFeet = int.Parse(totalSqFtTextBox.Text);
            int totalOccupiedSquareFeet = int.Parse(occupiedSqFtTextBox.Text);
            decimal grossRentsFirstYear = decimal.Parse(grossRentsFirstYearTextBox.Text);
            decimal grossRentsSecondYear = decimal.Parse(grossRentsSecondYearTextBox.Text);
            int loanAmount = int.Parse(loanAmountTextBox.Text);
            double interestRate = double.Parse(interestRateTextBox.Text);
            int loanTerm = int.Parse(yearlyLoanTermTextBox.Text);                                    
        }
        protected void performAnalysisButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Analysis analysis = new Analysis();
            analysis.GrossRentFirstYear = decimal.Parse(grossRentsFirstYearTextBox.Text);
            analysis.GrossRentSecondYear = decimal.Parse(grossRentsSecondYearTextBox.Text);
            analysisAndComments.Text = String.Format("{0}", analysis.PerformAnalysis());
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understood your question very well. Perhaps you should detail more about the flow of the user actions, how he fills those textboxes. You can declare your totalSquareFeet variable in the Default class (outside any method) as a private field and modify it in any method you want, but I would not advise for this approach as the totalSquareFeet variable will live as long as your webform class. Perhaps you can access totalSqFtTextBox.Text in your performAnalysis action and parse it again. Seems more natural.

Comment: All the local variables that I have declared under the okButton_Click method, I would like to use them under performAnalysisButton_Click method. I was wondering if there is a way I can avoid parsing the textbox data again?

Comment: Are you building a website that will only be used by a single person at a time? If not, you do *not* want to be thinking about "global variables". Every users data would end up overwriting each others values.

Comment: Yes, it will be a simple application used by a single user. I am still new to programming.

Comment: @Amit, there are smarter approaches than global variables. If you don't want to parse texts, you should try more user restrictive controls than asp:TextBox. For example I used Telerik.RadNumericTextBox which is a derived class that only accepts numeric inputs, which you can access through a Value property.

Answer (score 2):

After roundtrip the page returns to the client and there will be no information saved on the server unles you save it somewhere. Meaning you can hold the extra information on the page inside a hiddenfield or you can store it inside a Session or ViewState

**Session** This will be saved on the server(Also available if you go to other page)

```
Session["totalSquareFeet"] = totalSquareFeet;
```

Then you can read it back in `performAnalysisButton_Click`

```
int totalSquareFeet = (int)Session["totalSquareFeet"];
```

if you wanna clean the Session var after leaving page you can do

`Session["totalSquareFeet"] = null;`

**ViewState** This will be saved on the page(Credits to [Alexandru Popa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3071889/alexandru-popa))

```
ViewState["totalSquareFeet"] = totalSquareFeet;
```

Read

```
int totalSquareFeet = (int)ViewState["totalSquareFeet"];
```

**Hiddenfield** This will be saved on the page

store it in a   `<asp:HiddenField ID="HiddentotalSquareFeet" runat="server" />`

```
HiddentotalSquareFeet.Value = totalSquareFeet.ToString();
```

And read it back

```
if(int.TryParse(HiddentotalSquareFeet.Value, out int totalSquareFeet)){

}
```

Comment: If you will use that variable inside a single Web Form, and not across different pages, Session is not the way to go, because it caches your variables for the entire life cycle of your user session. You should use ViewState (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx) which only lives on a single page.

Comment: @AlexandruPopa i gave a way of how it could be done. You can also set the session to null when you leave the page and that problem will be fixed.

Comment: @ HMikhaeljan of course Session works very well. I only wanted to point out that, as your application grows, you should not overuse the Session class, as it leads to some spaghetti code across pages that is hard to follow and it is quite consuming in terms of memory.

Comment: @AlexandruPopa i agree on that. Its a good comment I will add viewstate to the answer to make it more complete answer

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question right...

To declare a variable as global, all you need to do is to declare it outside of the function and inside of the class that you are working in:

```
public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    int totalSquareFeet = 0;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventsArg e)
    { // And the rest of the code should be the same...
    }
    // Same code as you had...
}
```

So, it's al about removing the declaration from within the function to the outside.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by declaring properties at the class level and that became my global variables which I can access in button methods. Now I don't need to parse textbox values again in the button methods. See example below:

```
 public int totalSquareFeet
    {
        get { return int.Parse(totalSqFtTextBox.Text); }
        set { int.Parse(totalSqFtTextBox.Text); }
    }
```

Comment: That works, but trust me Amit, that is very bad design. If you have 20-30 different textbox controls on a single page, will you create properties with getters and setters for each of them? There is no need to store your variables in a page when the framework already does that for you. I suggest you to read how to create your own custom control in asp.net (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y6wb1a0e.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) .

Comment: Thanks, @AlexandruPopa for your recommendations. To be honest with you my experience is so limited that I can't differentiate between good or bad design. However, I am learning and this forum has been an excellent source specifically inputs from experienced developers.