# How can I use ViewState with this code? - Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is inside of `Repeater_ItemCommand`. I want to learn how to use this code to store in a `ViewState`, since on postback, the properties that I implement is lost.

```
if (e.CommandName == "PageNumbers")
             {
                 GridView1.PageIndex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

                 Repeater RepeatTD = (Repeater)GridView1.TopPagerRow.FindControl("Repeater1");

                 foreach (RepeaterItem item in RepeatTD.Items)
                 {
                     HtmlTableCell cell = (HtmlTableCell)item.FindControl("cell");
                     cell.Attributes["style"] = "background-color:blue";
                 }
                 RepeaterItem selectitem = (RepeaterItem)(((LinkButton)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer);
                 HtmlTableCell currentcell = (HtmlTableCell)selectitem.FindControl("cell");
                 currentcell.Attributes["style"] = "background-color:#ff6600";

             }
             GridView();
             Repeater();
```

Comment: Already gave a answer like this one. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49941599/7324631) for examples

Comment: can't you give an example where I can put the RepeaterItem selectitem into a ViewState?

Answer (score 1):

A example as asked for.

To save the RepeaterItem

```
RepeaterItem selectitem = (RepeaterItem)(((LinkButton)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer);

ViewState["selectItem"] = selectitem ;
```

To read the RepeaterItem

```
if(ViewState["selectItem"] != null){
  RepeaterItem selectItem = (RepeaterItem)ViewState["selectItem"];
}
```

Comment: repeater linkbutton doesn't work anymore after I put the viewstate, and after I changed it to session nothing really changed.

Comment: @RanielQuirante what are you exactly trying to achieve.

Comment: I need to change the background color of <td> where the link button is clicked

Comment: the link buttons is binded with the Repeater() it contains 1,2,3,4,5 to serve as a pagination to the gridview

Comment: @RanielQuirante you could save a list<int> in ViewState for the page numbers. The moment you load up new items do a for loop and find back the linkbutton and change background-color. You probably could also handle this completely clientside.

Comment: do you have any example so I may have an idea to your suggestion?

Comment: @RanielQuirante Sorry I'm a little busy at the moment to work it out completely. Pretty sure you can find something if you google "change repeater background-color"